# Compiling with dlib libraries

Tags: c++, linux, machine-learning, dlib

I'm trying to compile one of the examples in the dlib /examples folder.
If I keep everything as is (keep the example in the examples folder) then it works and compiler just fine.
However, if I move the example out of the folder (and adjust the path in the compile command accordingly), I get a "no such file or directory"

Obviously, I'm trying to do this because in a real scenario, I can't simply put all my code into the examples folder of the dlib library.

concretely:
the dlib libraries have been unpacked into my "Downloads" folder.
the example I'm trying to compile is bayes_net_ex.cpp
the command I'm using to compile the example is

```
g++ -O3 -I.. /home/user/Downloads/dlib/all/source.cpp -lpthread -lX11 bayes_net_ex.cpp
```

The error message is

```
bayes_net_ex.cpp:40:30: fatal error: dlib/bayes_utils.h: No such file or directory
#include <dlib/bayes_utils.h>
                          ^
```

compilation terminated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell your compiler where to look for #include files.  So add -I/home/user/Downloads/